# Render the published date/time formatted in ISO 8601 using Timber (.twig)

Tags: date-time

I am setting up Google Tag Manager's Data Layer and I have a .twig as my header file.  I need to produce the date and time of the post in ISO 8601 format.

```
"datePublished": "{{post.date}}"
```

This produces the date but not in the right format.  How do I format the date/Time to this standard?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you using Twig? Searching for "twig format date iso 8601" suggests using `|date("c")` as twig filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Kero, 
That was correct.

Here is the final code that works

```
"datePublished": "{{post.date|date('c')}}",
```

Here is the link

[How to format a datetime object to ISO 8601 in Twig](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/130/how-to-format-a-datetime-object-to-iso-8601-in-twig)

Thank you.